# What's standard data security practice on EC2?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, data-security

We're bringing up a webapp on EC2. Our passwords are held with a strong one way hash algorithm (SHA256, many iterations).

But what do people typically do for the rest of the data. Email addresses, birthdays, names and addresses.

We're based in the US and don't keep any financial or healthcare data. Just user profiles -- I believe there are few legal requirements, but what do people actually do.

We run EC2 app servers, MongoDB and and Amazon MySQL RDS instance. Performance is a consideration (we're expecting to have to scale out by necessity).

Comment: If you encrypt the data you store, you will have a difficult time searching it. I've never felt much of a need to encrypt basic user profile information. But then I don't do much in regulated industries.

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the rest of the user data before storing it. If it's not protected or sensitive data, and you're not running a site that's likely to be targeted, you can probably rely on standard security techniques when transmitting the data (e.g. SSL). But, if you would like to *store* the data more securely, here is a resource discussing [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_cryptography)

Here is a resource discussing performance implications of an encrypted MySQL DB:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11683/how-to-improve-performance-of-encrypted-mysql-database-on-linux-backend-server

Here is an example discussing a similar use case:

[How to store private encrypted user data in the database, but make them available to other chosen users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529582/how-to-store-private-encrypted-user-data-in-the-database-but-make-them-availabl)